# Adapt GNU/Linux to run specific command

Tags: linux

I wanna to create a OS to a specific task, (manage main OS disk). I'll burn the OS in a USB Drive / CD. I'll then boot the computer from the stick / CD to execute the tasks. I want to use linux scripts for this but I don't want all the utilities of a full Linux OS. I don't want either to run the script by myself so the task is done with just booting the CD / stick.

How can I do so? Any kind of help / orientation would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit: I've been surfing the net and I found something about Porteus OS. I may adapt it to do what I need. What do you guys think?

Comment: You should also look into how the Linux OS for Raspberry PI is built. That might give you insight about creating your own OS for your purpose. BTW, will Raspberry PI not do your job? It is a simple linux based single board computer to which you can connect USB HDD's

Comment: @Prasanna I already have Raspberry PI. But I want to edit the files of a OS from a simple device, as a usb stick. Which just burning a ISO, the user could just plug it on and boot it to access the tool, whereas the other option requires that the user has to buy a Raspberry Pi. If that weren't the problem, it would solve it as you say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest installing Arch Linux to a USB, grabbing the packages you need using pacman and then adding a systemctl service (to run a script that runs it) that runs on boot.

You can find information on how to do this in the following Arch Linux wiki pages:
[Arch Wiki - Installing Arch Linux on a USB key](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installing_Arch_Linux_on_a_USB_key)
[Arch Wiki - Systemd#Writing custom .service files](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Writing_custom_.service_files)

Comment: That's okay! :D